# Prevent automatic restore of fragment state in Android (and MVVMCross)

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvmcross

When a fragment is re-opened, Android automatically restores the state of the fragment and sets the values for any editable views that have an `android:id` specified.  When using MVVMCross, this causes the previous state to set the source value for bindings in the current view.  For example, if I open an editing fragment (which has a `EditText` for `BookTitle` with an ID) for Book_A and close the fragment, when opening the fragment to edit Book_B the `BookTitle` source value for Book_B is automatically updated with the last `EditText` value for Book_A.  This happens because Android automatically restored the state.

Is there a way to prevent Android from doing automatic state restoration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a [`MvxCachingFragmentActivity`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/bca16e523da23e5eeb9c7988a8a80f5fb581112c/MvvmCross/Droid/FullFragging/Caching/MvxCachingFragmentActivity.cs#L190) or through the support library v7 [`MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/blob/8774010593f5b5a806596f21db8b0b1480e83056/MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat/MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity.cs#L200) you can override `ShowFragment` and force the fragment to be re-created each time it is shown.

```
protected override void ShowFragment(
    string tag, 
    int contentId, 
    Bundle bundle, 
    bool forceAddToBackStack = false, 
    bool forceReplaceFragment = false)
{
    base.ShowFragment(tag, contentId, bundle, forceAddToBackStack, true);
}
```